# angular http post send complex objects

Tags: json, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular-httpclient

**My Service**

```
 public submitBooking(createBooking: CreateBooking) {
    const body = this.getSaveBookingRequestBody(createBooking);
    //const json = JSON.Stringify(body) //It throws 415 error
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'Save', body )
               .subscribe();
}

private getSaveBookingRequestBody(createBooking: CreateBooking): any {

    const body = {
        'Booking': {
            'Header': this.getBookingHeader(createBooking), //It works fine.
            'Items': [this.getBookingItems(createBooking)],
        },
        'TestOnly': !environment.production,
    };

    this.Logger.log(body);
    return body;
}


private getBookingItems(createBooking: CreateBooking): any {
    const bookingItem = {

        'CountryOfOrigin': createBooking.booking.countryoforigin,
        'VehicleValue': createBooking.booking.valueofvechicle,
        'SerialNumber': createBooking.booking.bookingNumber,
        'Description': createBooking.booking.description,
        'Mobility': createBooking.booking.mobility,
        'Currency': createBooking.booking.currency,
        'Weight': createBooking.booking.weight,
        'Year': createBooking.booking.year,
        'Cbm': createBooking.booking.cbm,

        //This is an array it doesn't work.
        'SubUnits':[
            createBooking.booking.relatedVehicles.forEach(element => {
                const units = {
                    'RelationType': element.relation,
                    'Weight': element.weight,
                    'Year': element.year,
                };
            })],
    };

    return bookingItem;
```

> When i create POST body the `SubUnits` always empty in WEB API. 
>   **How to loop through array and create an object for sending as body.**

*My angular model and WEB-API object are different*

I have also tried the `JSON.Stringify(unitsArray)` and returning it to SubUnits

```
const unitsArray = [];

createBooking.booking.relatedVehicles.forEach(element => {
        const units = {
            'RelationType': element.relation,
            'SerialNumber': element.chassisno,
            'Weight': element.weight,
            'Year': element.year,
        };
        unitsArray.push(units);
    });
SubUnits : JSON.stringify(unitsArray); // It also doesn't work with API.
```

Version : 
Angular 5
Typescript 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const bookingItem = {
...
    'SubUnits': [
        createBooking.booking.relatedVehicles.forEach(element => {
            const units = {
                'RelationType': element.relation,
                'Weight': element.weight,
                'Year': element.year,
            };
        })
    ]
...
};
```

This loop doesnt fill the array in `bookingItem.SubUnits`. `Array.forEach` does not return a value. Besides that, the variable `units` is never used. What you can do instead is create a new array using `Array.map`.

```
'SubUnits': [
    createBooking.booking.relatedVehicles.map(element => ({
        'RelationType': element.relation,
        'Weight': element.weight,
        'Year': element.year
    }))
]
```

This makes an array with 1 array element from `createBooking.booking.relatedVechiles`. I am not sure if that's what you are going for, but it is in your OP.

Comment: The foreach units was assigned it was another method. But your `map ` is working fine. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to not use JSON.stringify?  Just use:

```
  SubUnits :unitsArray;
```